# Unit Test of Retrofit 2 api call with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2

I need some advices on how to mock a rest api. My application is in MVP architecture.

My interface for API:

```
public interface MyAPI {

    @GET("{cmd}/{userName}/{password}")
    Observable<Response> login(
        @Path("cmd") String cmd,
        @Path("userName") String userName,
        @Path("password") String password
    );
```

My service:

```
public class MyService implements IService {

    private static MyService mInstance = new MyService();
    private MyAPI mApi;

    public static MyService getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    private MyService() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(Config.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.kBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .build();

        this.mApi = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
    }

    public void login(
        Subscriber<Response> subscriber,
        String userName,
        String password) {
        mApi.login(Config.kLoginCmd,userName,password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
    }
```

My presenter class:

```
public class LoginPresenter implements LoginContract.Presenter {

    LoginContract.View mView;
    IService mService;
    ISession mSession;

    public LoginPresenter(LoginContract.View loginView, IService service, ISession session) {
        mView = loginView;
        mService = service;
        mSession = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void login(String email, String password) {

        Subscriber<Response> subscriber = new Subscriber<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                mView.showLoading(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                mView.showError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response response) {
                if (response.getResults().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Config.kResultCodeOK)) {
                    mView.loginSuccess();
                } else {
                    mView.showError(response.getResults().getStatus().getErrmsg());
                }
            }
        };

        mView.showLoading(true);
        mService.login(
            subscriber,
            email,
            password);
    }
```

There is another way to test my presenter by writing a Mock service. But I don't like that so much and I think Mockito could help.

Here is my test class:

```
public class LoginPresenterMockTest {

    private LoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;

    @Mock
    LoginContract.View view;
    @Mock
    IService service;
    @Mock
    ISession session;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mLoginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(view, service, session);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginWithCorrectUserNameAndPassword() throws Exception {
        mLoginPresenter.login("user@email.com","password");
        verify(view).loginSuccess();
    }

}
```

What I want to do is I mock the response data call loginSuccess() when the response is correct.

Of course my current test will not work. I need some advices on how to mock this? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in next way:

```
@Test
public void testLoginWithCorrectUserNameAndPassword() throws Exception {
    // create or mock response object
    when(service.login(anyString(), anyString(), anyString).thenReturn(Observable.just(response));
    mLoginPresenter.login("user@email.com","password");
    verify(view).loginSuccess();
}

@Test
public void testLoginWithIncorrectUserNameAndPassword() throws Exception {
    // create or mock response object
    when(service.login(anyString(), anyString(), anyString).thenReturn(Observable.<Response>error(new IOException()));
    mLoginPresenter.login("user@email.com","password");
    verify(view).showError(anyString);
}
```

Comment: ```Mockito.when(service.login(any(),anyString(),anyString()).thenReturn(Observable.just(response)); ``` How to specify the first parameter? It's Subscriber<Response>. I can't cast it to any(). What should I do? Thanks

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that you pass subscriber. I think it is better to change your service method that it returns Observable and subscribe on it in presenter class. In this case provided code will work. Otherwise you should mock mApi.

Comment: Fix the issue by **ArgumentCaptor**

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for **@Ilya Tretyakov**, I came out this solution:

```
private ArgumentCaptor<Subscriber<Response>> subscriberArgumentCaptor;

@Test
public void testLoginWithCorrectUserNameAndPassword() throws Exception {
    mLoginPresenter.login("user@email.com","password");
    // create the mock Response object
    Response response = ......

    verify(service, times(1)).login(
        subscriberArgumentCaptor.capture(),
        stringUserNameCaptor.capture(),
        stringPasswordCaptor.capture()
    );

    subscriberArgumentCaptor.getValue().onNext(response);
    verify(view).loginSuccess();
}
```